# Trigger onEdit() function without manual user input using Unity Script and Sheets API

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-api

I have a simple function (onEdit) in the sheet which runs when there is a value in **cell C4**, but it only happens if the user manually inputs a value in this cell. Is there any way that we can run this function using unity script.

Like if we find a way that puts data in **cell C4** as a result this would trigger the below `copyValues` function (onEdit). I have tried to do it using the following formula that if cell C4 is not empty then it should run the function:

```
=IF(C4=<>"",copyValues(),"No")
```

And the sample script that I want to run is:

```
function copyValues() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var targetSheetName = "Sheet1"; 
  var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  
  var rangeToCopy = targetSheet.getRange('C5:E5');
  var destinationRange = targetSheet.getRange('F5:H5');
  
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(destinationRange, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

But this formula does not run a function when **cell C4** is not empty. How can we develop a script in Unity that inputs data in a sheet and trigger this above script? Any guidance/workaround would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the detailed situation of `Is there any way that we can put the data in cell C4 by external source and it would trigger the above script?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? For example, when the cell "C4" is edited by Sheets API, I think that the OnChange trigger can be used. When the cell "C4" is edited by a script, I think that your expected result can be achieved by modifying the script. But, I cannot know your actual situation. So, I cannot propose a clear answer. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: yes, you understood it correctly. How can we use Sheets API to edit the C4?

Comment: for example if we write data in google form using unity and then this form (on submission) will be able to trigger the function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `for example if we write data in google form using unity and then this form (on submission) will be able to trigger the function.`, I guess that the script of Unity edits the cell by Sheets API. In this case, I think that the OnChange trigger can be fired. How about this? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the solution, thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't know how to write the script in Unity to edit the sheets cell, Can you please guide me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I apologize, but I don't know how to write the script in Unity to edit the sheets cell, Can you please guide me.`, in this case, I would like to recommend updating your question and changing your tags or posting it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. By the way, in your updated question, it seems that your current script of Unity is not shown. So, I recommend providing your current script.

Comment: I apologize, using unity for this was just my idea, I do not have script in it, or can we use simple webapp for this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I apologize, using unity for this was just my idea, I do not have script in it, sorry`, in this case, for example, you have already had the script for authorizing the scopes? For example, a simple script for editing the cell is your expected answer? In order to help users think of your expected answer, how about including more information?